# How to hide $ sign while using interpolation in flutter new version?

Tags: flutter

I'm currently using string interpolation with a TextWidget it works fine but unfortunately it is returning a $ with the text and it should not be, i don't know why it's happening it might be because of flutter new version!
Can someone help me please!

You can find a picture of my problem down below.

Also here is my code:

HomeScreen.dart

```
Center(
            child: LocaleText(
              value.asLiters()!, //asLiters came from interpolation widget
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
            ),
          );
```

InterpolationWidget.dart

```
extension NumExtension on num {
  String? asLiters() {
    return "${this.toInt()} L";
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCrOz.jpg)

Comment: Your extension works as expected, you can even remove `this` keyword, it is not needed. The image result must be from different line.

Comment: 1. `asLiters` would not include the `$` in the resulting `String`.  As mentioned, the unexpected appearance must be caused from somewhere else. 2. `asLiters` cannot return `null`, so there is no reason for it to return a nullable type (and for callers to need to use `!`). 3. Assuming you're using [`package:flutter_locales`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_locales), I don't think you're using `LocaleText` correctly.  I think that the first argument is expected to be a key in a localization file and therefore should be a fixed string. (Do you have a `.json` file that has `"1914": "$1914"`?)

Comment: the value 1914 comes from database, so i think the problem is from the package it self because when i use the Text widget it's working fine but when i use LocaleText widget with string interpolation unfortunately it keeps returning the $ in the UI

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
extension NumExtension on num {
  String? asLiters() {
    return this.toInt().toString() + " L";
  }
}
```

Comment: Type mistake, I edited the code.